# Helvetica Neue font renders element sizes differently than Helvetica

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, ligature

Having two simple elements and CSS like here in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq9rskex/1/):

```html
<span class="text">f</span><span class="text">fl</span>
```

```css
.text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue"
}
```

When running the code in Chrome, the first span width covers all of the text while the second span width is 0. When I change the font to Helvetica, both spans have correct and expected width appropriate to the text within them.

My understanding is that it is somehow related to [ffl | Latin small ligature](https://graphemica.com/%EF%AC%84) and my guess is that the former font contains the ffl ligature while the latter does not.

Is there a way how to work-around it and selectively disable transformation of certain Unicode characters while using "Helvetica Neue"? Or do I simply need to use a different font?

Just found that [font-variant-ligature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures) might be a solution. Its not obvious to me what all ligatures does it affects, though. I need to work-around the issue just for small Latin ligatures. Namely, these Unicode characters:

- U+FB00 (ﬀ): ff
- U+FB01 (ﬁ): fi
- U+FB02 (ﬂ): fl
- U+FB03 (ﬃ): ffi
- U+FB04 (ﬄ): ffl

..but not affect any complex language like Japanese, Arabic etc.

Comment: there's something that confused me in this question.. I prepared a whole demo to show the point but I think it's too far fetched if I didn't first clarified this fact. I first crafted an html snippet including a fontface declaration bound to the Helvetica Neue font family. After that I tried to render the ligatures you showed in your question but the zero width you were talking about never occurs. I didn't share the code because the way you described the issue is looking for answer around the ligatures. The demo just showed that they correctly render with no added settings

Comment: styling the elements to show or not the ligatures always correctly accomodated and the text was correctly shown. There's an actual scenario you could show behaving like you said with zero width?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have messed the first link to JSFiddle during the edit (fixed now). Even when running that simple JSFiddle example if you inspect elements in CDT, you'll see that the first span is occupying width of all three characters (like if it's a ligature) wherease the second one has zero width.

Comment: I think that's a misunderstanding. Those are still two separate spans.. the first one containing the text `f` and the second one the text `fl`. None of them is zero width and you may measure their exact px size doing `.offsetWidth` in js. The ligatures are rendered based on the font support to it.. so that if combination of characters are expected to be more visible if shown as ligature and the font has them, those combinations will be shown in a special way (and in the web domain this behaviour can be also controlled through the css property you highlighted in your question)

Comment: but yet I could also speculate you are not seeing the Helvetica Neue rendered.. unless you have such font installed in your system.. are you using a mac maybe? In my case I see it rendered as Times New Roman for example. Unless I explicitely include a fontface.

Comment: you can see yourself those are still 2 separate divs just adding `border: solid` to your css rule

Comment: to fill the whole picture, you can explicitely use ligatures using those unicode like `&#xFB00;` and in that case if the font has them, they will be shown as that

Comment: My bad, should have said that before. Yeah I'm using Mac (which means the font is available and comes for free). And the `offsetWidth` of the second span is 0 in that case.

Comment: To add some clarity (hopefully) :) ..what I'm specifically interested about is the width of the elements. I've included the information about ligature because it obviously relate but what I'm trying to achieve is to use the same font, yet avoid the browser to render those specific latin ligatures as one character (because that make the second span to have zero width which causes some consequent issues that are specific to the application I'm developing).

Comment: since the size of `inline`elements (such is the span by default) is given by their content.. I may assume that in your system the text gets aggregated in one phrasal unit to accomodate for the ligature... and in that case it may make sense to have the second span as zero width. I just can't verify myself with the woff I used because it behaves differently. Anyway maybe the suggestion given in the answer did the job?

Comment: At the same time, I need to avoid general solutions like the CSS style because, unless they are specified very precisely, they can easily influence (in my case break) other languages for which complex ligatures are typical.

Comment: did you try to force `font-variant-ligatures: none;` or `font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;`? what's the outcome in this specific case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and participation man! 

Yeah, the answer bellow is correct and working on the simple sample but I won't be able to use it (again, it's too general and it'd negatively influence other parts of the system). I was ideally looking for solution where I could somehow list above 5 ligatures and exclude them from being processed by the font.

Comment: Yes,`font-variant-ligatures: none;` works fine as well as `font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;`. But I haven't been able to find detailed spec of list of ligatures it excludes. And thus, I can't use it safely due to many languages potentially depending on it.

Comment: @MartinJaníček Another option is to edit the font and remove those ligatures, and of course host that font. Or use JavaScript to dynamically add the style I posted below

Comment: I agree with the chance of hosting your own font and include it in the html instead of relying on the installed fonts. If it's really important for you to know how ligatures will be handled for sure. By the way I've finally got how the asnwer given worked.. and it makes sense. The `inline-block` adds "size" to the element and it's expected to prevent the aggregation of separate texts given by the ligatures.

Comment: >Another option is to edit the font and remove those ligatures, and of course host that font

This would actually deserve separate answer but agree. Copyright might be an issue in that case but good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `span` `display:inline-block`

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.text, 
.text_old {
  background: radial-gradient(white, red);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>With "inline-block"</p>
<span class="text">f</span><span class="text">fl</span>
 

<p>Without "inline-block"</p>
<span class="text_old">f</span><span class="text_old">fl</span>
```

Comment: can you please explain which exact problem did this solution solve?

Comment: @DiegoD I added before and after examples, notice the individual gradients, which mean that the spans are not longer welded into one by the ligature.